# How to change message details (email body) in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsuserdefaults, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, xcode4.6

I seem to have fallen fowl of something that seems like it should be very simple!

How do I now populate an email's body with the strings a user has entered into NSUserDefaults?

Basically there is a button else ware that enters a sting such as 'YES' into NSUserDetaults. How do I make the email body those stored strings.

This is the code I currently have:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"SYS"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"How do I make this the content of NSUSERDEFAULTS?" isHTML:NO];
controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Using your code the strings appear as : Yes, No, Maybe, No way,

How can I alter the format to make them appear

Yes,

No,

Maybe,

No way.

Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a line break character, which can be achieved with `\n` (newline).

```
NSArray *storedStrings = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourStoredKey"];
NSMutableString *messageBody = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *aString in storedStrings) {
    [messageBody appendFormat:@"%@,\n\n", aString];
}
[messageBody deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(messageBody.length-3, 3)];
[controller setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
```

That line I added right after the for loop will remove the last three characters from the string, i.e. the two newline characters and the comma.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. Your code is pretty much spot on! It is an array of strings that ends up in NSUserDefaults so your second block of code is ideal. 
One final thing though, do you know how I could alter that code so that a)the stings appear vertically one on top of each other (I have updated the question with an example) b) the final string has a full stop after it instead of a comma? 

Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for you help, I really appreciate it! Your update answers my question perfectly. If you happen to have a spare second could you also have a look at my other unanswered question- "Issue with Xcode UIImageView layout" (just head through my profile). I'm sure it's going to be something stupidly simply too, but so far I have no answers! I think it has passed people by. 
Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"SYS"];
[controller setMessageBody:[[nsstring stringwithformat@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourStoredKey"]]  isHTML:NO];
controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```